# Группировка фото через бота в aiogram3

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Допустим есть echo-bot, проблема возникает, когда юзер отправляет сразу несколько фотографий, и бот их отправляет каждую отдельно. Я пытался сделать примерно так:

```
    if message.content_type in ['photo', 'document']:
        photos_ids = [photo.file_id for photo in message.photo]
        print(f"photo_ids: {photos_ids}")
        media = [InputMedia(media=photo_id) for photo_id in photos_ids]
        print(f"media: {media}")
        for medias in media:
            print(f"medias: {medias}")
```

После отправки боту одной фотографии я получаю 3 file_id одной фотографии(они отличаются лишь в двух символах по индексам -7 и -6), была идея просто оставить все что левее этих символов, но тогда телеграмм не поймет что именно хочет отправить бот.
Вопрос: Каким образом можно исправить это, чтобы бот когда получал несколько фото отправлял их обратно в таком же виде(не просто пересылал, а именно отправлял)

Comment: Ээээ, а какой вопрос-то?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос